# Filter values where combination of two columns in one table matches another table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working in Google Sheets and trying to create a FILTER function that returns only the results from a second table where a pair of values exists in the first table. Here's a simplified example:

SpellsInitial (Table 1)

| Level | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Heal |
| 2 | Flaming Sphere |
| 3 | Fireball |

SpellsHeightened (Table 2)

| Level | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Heal |
| 2 | Flaming Sphere |
| 2 | Heal |
| 3 | Fireball |
| 3 | Flaming Sphere |
| 3 | Heal |

And I want to filter SpellsHeightened to return only the results that are in SpellsInitial—essentially "(Level=Level)*(Name=Name)=1".

I have a FILTER function taking a level value as input to print a list of names, but I can't seem to get the ArrayFormula part to work.

`=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(SpellsHeightened_Name, A30=SpellsHeightened_Level, (SpellsHeightened_Name=SpellsInitial_Name)*(A30=SpellsInitial_Level)))`

I know what I actually need on the last line is "the value on a given line in SpellsHeightened_Name" because otherwise it's the whole array, but I guess I'm struggling to identify and pass in that value using only a level value as input. I tried nesting one FILTER (to get the list of names from Heightened) inside a second FILTER (to match the names up with Initial) but could get that figured out either.

[Here's the actual thing in practice.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X4kM4tuGpuzX-Lz66EC-ogdnPRi1UDgpArrigEpMNGc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: post & ghost... ?

Comment: Sorry, missed the first notification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
=FILTER( SpellsHeightened,
         ISNUMBER( MATCH( SpellsHeightened_Level&SpellsHeightened_Name,
                          SpellsInitial_Level&SpellsInitial_Name, 0 ) ) )
```

[image: result]

Comment: I ended up adding this as a helper column instead, but this answer is correct! And thank you for reminding me that ISNUMBER(MATCH) is a thing. I was adding an unnecessary step by using an INDEX(MATCH) instead.